# Prevent a ContextMenu from Hiding once Shown

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a `ContextMenu` in my form which I want to be shown all the time. But when I click one of its items or anywhere in the form it hides itself. Is there a way to prevent it from hiding?

Comment: What you want is not a menu. Find a different UI element to display this list.

Comment: I just like the look of `ContextMenu`.

Comment: To @David's point, if I saw something like this, I'd be perpetually hitting the Escape key or right mouse button trying to make it go away. Consider an alternate way of displaying this information.